# Change instance type based on a time schedule in Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-auto-scaling

I have only 1 Linux instance.

Can we auto change the instance type based on a time schedule?

Eg: During day time I want t3a.2xlarge and after evening I want it changed to t3.small based on a time schedule.

Comment: I doubt there is something OTB that does this, but you could accomplish with a scheduled lambda.

Comment: By the way, your instance needs to be in stopped state. Is it feasible for you? Else, think of autoscaling which is built for this purpose.